# MySQL query to delete Joomla user with same first & last name

Tags: mysql, joomla

I know this isn't correct, but this is basically what I want to do:

```
delete FROM jos_users WHERE name like '<firstname>=<lastname>'
```

In Joomla the name `field` is one input and there are a lot of spam accounts that have the same first & last name - for example Uzhuzaio Uzhuzaio - that I would like to delete.

So in summary, I need a query that will delete the users from `jos_users` where the `name` field contains 2 of the same word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index), which returns a substring before or after a certain number of occurrences of a delimiter.
In the example below, space is the delimiter, and a count of 1 will return everything to the left of the first space and a count of -1 everything on the right of the first space.

```
DELETE FROM jos_users WHERE 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, " ", 1)=SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, " ", -1)
```

I would however perform a SELECT first, to see that there is no legitimate user in there (rare, but it could happen)

Important note: this only works if the name is in the form `<name> <surname>`. Multiple spaces will pose a problem. In the case of multiple spaces (e.g. `<composite name> <composite name>`) you should use different count values (`2;-2` `3;-3` etc).

Answer (score 2):

I think that

```
DELETE FROM jos_users WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, '=', 1 ) = SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, '=', -1 )
```

should do the trick, have you tried it?

Comment: For the sake of the OP, never use the table prefix when writing queries for Joomla. Always replace with `#__` so the table name should look like `#__users`. Note that there are 2 underscores.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for that, or is just a good practice? If I remember correctly, during Joomla's installation you can/should set the table prefix, so it should be always the same thorugh all the database. Am I missing something?

Comment: If `#__` wansn't used and I downloaded an extension like JomSocial, I would have to change all the queries to suit my database table prefix needs. People have different prefixes so it makes it a global definition, simply making life a lot easier.

Comment: @lodder this didn't work, but i changed DELETE to SELECT * before i actually tested a delete query. i got this: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1.  then i changed #__users to jos_users and it returned all of my users

Comment: @user1855769 - The query might not have worked however I was just pointing out that you should always define a Joomla database table using `#__users` if you're running the query from a Joomla file. Are you running it from a Joomla file or from phpMyAdmin?

Comment: @user1855769 - you should have mentioned that in your question lol.

Comment: @lodder thanks for the help. a friend pointed out another little nugget i forgot to mention - virtuemart is installed too. this was a good thing though, because we managed to accomplish what i was looking to do with a few queries.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla by default does not have separate fields for first and last names. Most likely you have them separated by some symbol. I would recommend to define it and write a simple PHP code. At least this is what I would do.